# Allowing installation of Microsoft.Speech dll even when prerequisite is not available

Tags: c#, wpf, gac

I have an application which should optionally pull TTS voices from Microsoft Server Speech Platform.  If the Platform has not been installed (via ClickOnce), the application should gracefully continue.  However, as it stands, the whole application fails to install if this is missing.  This seems to come automatically from the dll before anything is even called.  Help!

The SDK with Microsoft.Speech.dll can be found here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=1b1604d3-4f66-4241-9a21-90a294a5c9a4

The error is "System Update Required: Unable to install or run the application requires that assembly Microsoft.Speech Version 10.1.0.0 be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) first".  Again, the goal is to allow the application to install even Microsoft.Speech has not yet been installed.

In the ClickOnce Options for Prerequisites this is not present, it seems to be coming from the dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will work, but have not been able to test:

In Publish -> Application Files set the publish status to 'Exclude' or 'Include' for Microsoft.Speech.dll

The key is in the ClickOnce Manifest, it's not hidden in a dll.

Let me know if this works

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm looking, and I think I want to include Microsoft.Speech.dll.  The issue is that the .dll calls on something else that has to be installed in the GAC, because I think installing the Microsoft.Speech runtime may not actually deliver the dll, but I'll check it.

Comment: Actually, I've just checked it.  You are right on the money on this.

Comment: Now I wonder if I can use Isolated for this instead of requiring the user to install to the GAC.

Comment: 'Include' should work too. The error you are getting is during the clickOnce installation, correct? I just tested deploying this on a machine without speech using both exclude and include options and it installed successfully both ways

Comment: I originally thought that you planned on installing this separately for some reason, which is why i said use 'exclude'. The 'Include' should work...

Comment: Microsoft.Speech.dll doesn't need to be in your GAC, it's just that if the assembly referencing that assembly can't find the assembly, that's the last place it will look for it. The include option will basically copy that assembly right along side the application assembly and the application will be able to find it.

Comment: Though I think that the installer never installs Microsoft.Speech.dll, and what I want is Include instead of Exclude.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this, which works for me.

Import Microsoft.Speech.dll from the following location:

```
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Speech\11.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Speech.dll
```